# No module named mysql even thought the code was wroking earlier

Tags: python, mysql, visual-studio-code, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ioi9a.png)

```
import mysql.connector as sqlcon
con1=sqlcon.connect(host="localhost",user='root',passwd='ishaan094',database='db1')
if con1.is_connected():
    print('Connection established.')
else:
    print('COnnection not established.')
cur1=con1.cursor()
cur1.execute('select * from empl')
data=cur1.fetchall()
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

The code was working perfectly when I first created it.

Later I forgot the password to mysql, tried to change it following the instructions on the mysql website but failed in doing so.
Found a notepad where I had written the original mysql pwd(which still works)
Tried to run the code again but it doesn't work anymore saying the module is not there.

I have check pip list and it show mysql-connector-python and pymysql as installed.

Comment: Please add code as text not a screen shot

Comment: Code added as txt @EmiOB

Comment: Is the problem still there? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

There may be multiple python environments on your machine.

Check that the interpreter environment you are currently using is the one with the `pymsql` package installed.

Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> **Python:Select Interpreter** switch to use the correct interpreter.

[image]

The best way is to use a virtual environment to manage your 3rd party packages and python versions.